# Grunt run task for another Grunt file

Tags: gruntjs

I have 3 separate apps in 3 different folders. e.g. folder1, folder2 and folder3. folder3 is the combination of folder1 and folder2. Right now, I run dist task on both folder1 and folder2, then with bower link I link those dist folders with in folder3. Is there any way I could run a task with in folder3 that will create dist on folder1 and folder2, and link them with folder3? In short I want to run grunt task of folder1 and folder2 from folder3 and link them.

```
grunt.config.set('exec', {
    loginapp: {
       command: 'grunt -b C:/project/loginapp dist'
    }
});

grunt.registerTask('all', [
   'exec:loginapp'
]);
```

Folder structure

```
c:\project
    ----loginapp
       dist
       GruntFile.js
    ----webapp
        public
            bower_components
                dist-loginapp
        GruntFile.js
```

Hope this helps. I am in webapp > GruntFile where I run dist and that should run dist task on loginapp before its on dist task.

Comment: that is not very clear. add the related code please

Comment: In short I want to run dist task for other project and include that as a bower component within my project. Idea is if I have multiple projects as included as bower component with in my project then instead of going to individual projects, run dist and then include them in my project, I want that if I run dist on my main project then that task should run dist on my given projects list and link them as well.

Comment: What do you means by "link them"? You want to create a grunt task to run grunt task of other project that's right?

Comment: right. for now, thats my first step.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-b` flag to specify an alternate base path where there is a Gruntfile.

Then use [grunt-exec](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-exec) to create task that run grunt task of your other projects.

**E.g** :

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.config.set('exec', {
        distFolder1: {
            command: 'grunt -b relative/path/to/Gruntfile/of/folder1 taskName'
        },
        distFolder2: {
            command: 'grunt -b relative/path/to/Gruntfile/of/folder2 taskName'
        },
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-exec');
};
```

Now you just have create a register task that run these two task and you other task.

**E.g** :

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('distAndLink', [
        'exec:distfolder1',
        'exec:distfolder2',
        // your other task (bower link)
    ]);
};
```

and then run `grunt distAndLink` from folder 3.

Comment: I tried that. But it runs dist task on the same GruntFile whereas I want it to run dist on my folder1.